# Why object property throwing error in parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Why parameter index value throwing error, but if I put ternary operator like

```
item?.unit ? item.unit:''  then it is accepted
```

point.sum = point.sum * conversionFactorArr[**item.unit**].conversionFactor; (ERROR)

Comment: "Why parameter index value throwing error" — What error?

Comment: Please read [ask]; in particular the part about providing a [mcve].

Comment: You've tagged this [tag:node.js] and [tag:express] but nothing in your question mentions them, or uses any features provided by them. All  your (provided) code is pure JS.

Answer (score -1):

item?.unit checks if item exists and has a defined unit property, if it does, the expression evaluates to item.unit; otherwise, it evaluates to ''.

This way, if item is null or undefined, the expression won't throw an error and instead provide an empty string as the fallback value.

If item.unit is null or undefined, it could cause an error when trying to access conversionFactorArr[item.unit] because the index would be invalid, by using the ternary operator, you're providing a fallback value ('') when item.unit is null or undefined. This ensures that the index used to access conversionFactorArr is always valid and prevents the error from occurring.